# Is this formula wrong or correct?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, distance

My physics teacher wrote this formula at the board :

a = (Vf - Vi)t / 2

But I've been studying and all sources I have found state the next :

x = (Vf - Vi)t / 2

And

a = (Vf - Vi)/t

Please confirm me if I'm right or wrong

Comment: -1. No research effort. You could look up the formulas for constant acceleration on the internet - there are many sites. If still confused you could discuss this with your teacher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A lesson in dimensional analysis**

A useful tool you'll find is called [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis). You consider what each variable is a measure of. For example acceleration is $m s^{-2}$ so you know that is a measure of length ($[L]$) and the inverse of time squared ($[T]^{-2}$).

So taking your example:

$$ a= \frac{v_{f}-v_{i}}{2}  t $$ 
We have:
$$ [L][T]^{-2} = ([L][T]^{-1} - [L][T]^{-1}) [T] $$
Where the 2 has no dimensions and so can be ignored.
$$ [L][T]^{-2} = ([L][T]^{-1}) [T] $$
adding or subtracting two velocities would still give you a velocity. Multiplying the velocity by time gives:
$$ [L][T]^{-2} = [L] $$
Which, I hope you can see, is incorrect. The right hand side provides a length (the units of your distance travelled).

This is a useful tool and can be used to advise you on the correctness of equations*. It is easy for a teacher to accidentally write the wrong thing - if you practice this technique of dimensional analysis you will find yourself in less confusion in the future.

*Note, watch out for constants (eg the gravitational constant, spring constant...etc) for many of them do have units. Also just because something is dimensionally correct doesn't mean it is the right equation, only that you can say one is wrong if it is not dimensionally correct.

Comment: This is a very useful lesson for beginners.I use this tool everytime I see a multiple choice question in physics exams.

Answer (score 0):

|  | Definition |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| velocity | $\bar{v}=\dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\dfrac{x_{f}-x_{i}}{t_{f}-t_{i}}$ | $\dfrac{v_f + v_i}{2}$ |
| acceleration | $\bar{a}=\dfrac{\Delta{v}}{\Delta{t}}=\dfrac{v_{f} – v_{i}}{t_{f} – t_{i}}$ | $\dfrac{v_f - v_i}{t}$ |

> My physics teacher wrote this formula at the board : $a = \dfrac{(V_f - V_i)t}{2}$

This is incorrect. The correct formula is: $a = \dfrac{(V_f - V_i)}{t}$. See the definition of [acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration).

> But I've been studying and all sources I have found state the next : $x = \dfrac{(V_f - V_i)t}{2}$

This is also incorrect. Substitute $a = \dfrac{(V_f - V_i)}{t}$ into $s = ut + \dfrac12 at^2 $. The correct formula is $s = \dfrac{(V_f + V_i)t}{ 2}$.